# Load h5mu data from python in R to create a seurat object?

Tags: r, seurat

I'm trying to load .h5mu data into R, but I can't seem to find any options for this. I have found a way to do it with .h5ad (anndata) but not .h5mu - any ideas here?

I was also thinking about using the 'Convert' function in SeuratDisk for this, but it appears that SeuratDisk cannot be found anymore in the most recent R when trying to use 'install.packages(SeuratDisk)'.

I hope some of you can help!

Best,
Lasse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can get said functionality from  [MuDataMAE](https://rdrr.io/github/PMBio/MuDataMAE/man/readH5MU.html) .
So far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with the `python` language but rather a defined format for storing some data.

Comment: I might add that this was a case of LMGTFY - I used the search terms "CRAN R load h5mu"